# Getting issue after composer update

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to update composer but getting the below error

```
 Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle dev-develop, it is found yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle[dev-develop] in the lock file and yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle[dev-closure-di, dev-master, dev-L4, dev-L5-DT1.9, 1.3.0, ..., v1.5.0, v2.0.0, ..., v2.2.2, v3.0.0, ..., v3.6.13, v4.0.0, ..., v4.3.3, v5.0.0-beta, ..., v5.12.5, v6.0.0-alpha, ..., v6.29.3, v7.0.0, ..., v7.10.3, v8.0.0, ..., v8.13.7, v9.0.0, ..., v9.18.1] from composer repo (https://repo.packagist.org) but these do not match your constraint and are therefore not installable. Make sure you either fix the constraint or avoid updating this package to keep the one from the lock file.
```

My laravel version 5.5

I try below command but nothing happened

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:"~8.0"
composer self-update --stable
composer self-update --1
```

I dont know why this happen anyone have idea then please let me know